# Anyone seen Apex tests failing in production after Winter 15 Upgrade?

Tags: apex, failing-tests

Just wondering if anyone has seen an issue where tests that were running just fine (Pass) in production Org started failing after Winter '15 upgrade?

Also we have plans to deploy some new Apex code to production soon but I've never had to try to do this with a test already failing in production - my new code is not related to the failing test/code.  My assumption is I first need to fix the failing tests and deploy that to production before deploying any new code, yes?  (bummer)

Comment: what is/are  the error(s) you see when you run all tests

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen that happen in unit tests. You can look at the known issues for [Winter '15](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=Winter%2015) or just known issues in general and see if any of them might be related to what you are observing.

One thing to check is whether or not you are running the tests in parallel execution mode.  I've observed some tests run in parallel will fail with unable to obtain lock errors.  When you deploy to production all tests are run serially, so if your tests only fail when run in parallel you don't have to worry about it preventing your deployment.

Another thing that I see all of the time is a production change such as a validation rule, a workflow, a record type, etc. is introduced and it causes unit tests to fail.  It is possible that something like that is the cause.

You do need to make sure that all unit tests in your org's namespace (i.e., your classes and unmanaged packages) pass with the deployment.  This means that it is OK if managed package unit tests are failing.  They will not prevent the deployment.